# Hive nested select statements

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to execute nested select statements in Hive -

```
select col1, (select COUNT(*) as cnt from table2) , col2 from table1;
```

When I run above query I am getting below exception -

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:8 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'COUNT' '(' in expression specification
```

I also tried assigning select count(*) to hivevar and using it in the query. But, Still I am getting same issue.

```
set hivevar:cnt=select COUNT(*) as cnt from table2;
select col1, ${hivevar:cnt} , col2 from table1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `WITH` clause and `CROSS JOIN` with the main table.

```
WITH t AS (SELECT COUNT (*) AS ct FROM table2)
SELECT s.col1, t.ct, s.col2
  FROM table1 s CROSS JOIN t
```